# how to call template function in class body?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, vector, iterator

i wrote the followig function that it search in the vector and find position of a pointer in the vector and if find is successful, return iterator:

```
template<class InputIterator>
InputIterator MainCore::findDeviceAccordingToIP ( const char * value )
{
    std::vector<Device *>::iterator first,last;
    first = this->devList->begin();
    last = this->devList->end();
    Device *temp;

    for ( ;first!=last; first++){
        temp = *first;

        if ( strcmp(temp->endpoint->IPAddress.c_str(),value) == 0)
        {
            return first;
            break;
        }
    }

    //return false;
}
```

Above code in cpp file in i put the following code in MainCore class in *.h file:

```
template<class InputIterator>    
InputIterator findDeviceAccordingToIP (const char *value );
```

Now When i call i another function such as:

```
this->findDeviceAccordingToIP("192.168.2.11");
```

Now i have two question :

1. When i compile it, i get the following error:

   `error: no matching function for call to MainCore::findDeviceAccordingToIP(const char [13])`
2. how i get return T and just booloean and iterator?

Comment: It almost looks like you are putting your template definition in a .cpp file.  You can't do that.  Declare and define your template in .h

Comment: There is no need for template in your code - the return type you probably want is `std::vector<Device*>::iterator`

Comment: Try to use std::string instead of const char *. It's faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning question 1, the template parameters of the function template have no dependence on the function parameters, so you need to specify the type explicitly:

```
this->findDeviceAccordingToIP<SomeIteratorType>("192.168.2.11");
```

Furthermore, the template code should be in the header file or in a file included by the header. It has to be included, directly or indirectly, by the client code.

Note that you could replace the whole function with a call to [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and a suitable functor.

As for question 2, it isn't clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

First question is answered above.

For the second question:

You want to return two types of values (iterarator and boolean), that is not possible with C++. You can have some possibilities

Make the iterator a reference parameter and return the result in this. Make the return value to return true/false to indicate the success of the search.

OR

Return the `last` in case you don't find the value. This can be easily coded like this.

```
template<class InputIterator> InputIterator MainCore::findDeviceAccordingToIP ( const char * value ) 
{     
    std::vector<Device *>::iterator first,last;     
    first = this->devList->begin();     
    last = this->devList->end();     
    Device *temp;      
    for ( ;first!=last; first++)
    {         
        temp = *first;          
        if ( strcmp(temp->endpoint->IPAddress.c_str(),value) == 0)
        {  
            break;         
        }     
    }      

    return first; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to the following function and instead of iterator i pass content of iterator as `Device *` :

```
bool MainCore::findDeviceAccordingToIP (const std::string& _IPAddress, Device * devPtr )
{
    std::vector<Device *>::iterator first,last;
    first = this->devList.begin();
    last = this->devList.end();
    Device *temp;

    for ( ;first!=last; first++){
        temp = *first;

        if ( temp->endpoint->IPAddress == _IPAddress )
        {
            devPtr = *first;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

So i get boolean result and by ref get result of content of vector, it's work fine.

Comment: This way you do not modify the `devPtr` outside of the function scope (in the caller); you need pass the pointer by reference: `bool MainCore::findDeviceAccordingToIP (const std::string& _IPAddress, Device* &devPtr )`

Comment: But i need to get result as boolean.

Comment: Indeed, you get result as boolean, but you do not get `devPtr` value outside of the function because of missing `&` symbol in method declaraction.